# Getting error publishing Silverlight 3 app on IIS 6 \ Windows 2003

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, publishing

I get the error below when I'm publishing a Silverlight 3 app on a IIS 6 \ Windows 2003 box.

The app is just a vs08>file>new project>Silverlight App with the mainpage having one textblock that says "TEST".

I get this error when I'm in IE only, but Firefox, Chrome just show nothing (no error and no app).  The error is a bit confusing since the error has "Mozilla" in it, but maybe that is something i'm not familiar with.

This server already has a Silverlight application on it that runs fine, although that one is a bit more complicated since there is an aspx login page first.

If I publish the test Silverlight app on my IIS5\XP box it work fine.  I just create new virtual dir and point to the website.

I'm assuming that i'm missing something that I need to do on IIS 6.  Or perhaps I'm just missing something else that is probably some obvious.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 22 Sep 2010 18:47:44 UTC
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: 2104 An error has occurred.    
Line: 56
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://<myserver name here>/Tester/SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the SilverlightApplication1TestPage.htm.  It might have to do with your ASP.NET setup on IIS, which is not needed to host a simple SL application.